Diffeomorphism invariance (gauge choice) and the pullback metric in General Relativity
If we have a diffeomorphism $f: M \to M$, and $g$ is a solution for Einstein field equations, then $f^*g$ is also a solution. Now, taking a solution $g$, we want to find a somewhat general expression for $g' = f^* g$. My professor used "infinitesimal translations" to derive in a very non-rigorous way the expression
$$ g'_{\mu \nu} = g_{\mu \nu} - \nabla_\mu \xi_\nu - \nabla_\nu \xi _\mu$$
for an arbitrary vector field $\xi$. I recognize here the known formula for the Lie derivative of the metric, so we can write this expression in a clearer way as
$$ g' = g - \mathcal{L}_\xi (g)$$
Which, seems a lot like the definition of the Lie derivative
$$ \mathcal{L}_\xi (g) = \frac{d}{dt} \phi^{t *} _\xi g \, \vert_{t=0} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} (\phi^{t *} _\xi g - g) $$
where $\phi_\xi$ is the flow of $\xi$.
However we have a limit here, we can't just get rid of it. 
Can you help me derive my professor's formula or, in case it is incorrect, to find a (somewhat) generic expression for $f^* g$?
Edit: I think I need to better explain my issue.
My professor is using the diffeomorphism invariance to fix a gauge. The diffeomorphism invariance states that, if $g$ is a solution of the field equations and f is a diffeomorphism, then $f^* g$ is also a solution. So I'd expect He is finding the generic form for $f^* g$ to find what gauges we can fix.  I think He is taking $f = \phi^t_\xi$, which is a class of diffeomorphisms. However, He then takes a first-order approximation around t=0, where f becomes the identity and $f^*g = g + \mathcal{L}_\xi g$. I have no issue with the derivation of this approximation. But this is just an approximation so we can't use it to actually fix the gauge. It is not even a diffeomorphism, as $f^*$ is the identity if $f$ is the identity, and in any case can't be a sum for any $f$. He calls it "infinitesimal diffeomorphism". This has no mathematical sense: this is not invariance under diffeomorphisms and we can't use it to fix a gauge.

in the formula $\xi$ is supposed to be infinitesimal. To answer your question, only the derivative of $g$ really makes sense, not $g'$. You can interpret these calculations as: we have a family of metrics parametrized by an interval and we compute the derivative of $g$ (and maybe of other things, such as the curvature) at $0$.

What is the definition of $f^*g$ that you know?

@Deane $f^* g \vert_p = g \vert_{f(p)} (df_p (\cdot), df_p (\cdot))$

It is not clear to me what an infinitesimal diffeomorphism means. I can understand that you find the starting equation if you stop at the first order, but it's an approximate solution. There is no real isomorphism that acts as the identity on the points but not as a pullback.

What’s your definition of $df_p$?

@Deane $df_p (X) = \frac{d}{d s} \vert_{s=0} (f \circ \phi^s_X(p))$

Ok. Now write formula for $\phi^s_X(p)$ in local coordinates, use that to write $df_p(X)$ in local coordinates, and finally $g_{f(p)}(df_p(\cdot),df_p(\cdot))$ in local coordinates.

I gotta say that the definitions you are using are not the easiest to work with. Where do they come from?

@user8268 I updated my question as I think I did not express my problem in a clear way

@Deane I believe those are the most generic definitions, if you just substitute the flow with a generic representative curve of the vector. I got them from my class in differential geometry and some graduate texts

Which graduate texts?

This is obviously not a true diffeomorphism, and indeed it can't be used to fix a gauge for the metric. He was mistaken when he stated this as something general.  
This first-order expansion around $t=0$ of the flux (infinitesimal translation along $\xi$) corresponds to the identity on points and as $$T \mapsto T + \mathcal{L}_\xi T $$ on tensors. It can still be used for approximate solutions, such as linearized gravity, to fix a gauge.  
It can also be used when variating the action to prove the conservation of the energy-stress tensor, using the diffeomorphism invariance by writing $$\delta S = \phi^{t *}_\xi S - S = 0$$ and taking the limit $t \to 0$.  
So while this was wrong in general, one can find some formal mathematical justification for the specific situations where he applied it.

Thanks to @ACuriousMind for the discussion that led to this conclusion.

Your point about how the infinitesimal diffeomorphism can be used to fix a gauge for linearized gravity is a good one. That's more likely to be what the professor is doing than what I wrote.

@Deane unfortunately my professor did this "by intuition" without any kind of formal geometry knowledge so I really had a hard time understanding these operations

I suggest trying to write this stuff in local coordinates. That often helps you understand the abstract formulas better.

I think you're misinterpreting what the professor is saying. An infinitesimal diffeomorphism is indeed not a diffeomorphism. Given a metric $g$ and a diffeomorphism $f$, the pullback metric is $f^*g$. Your professor's goal appears to be to find a diffeomorphism $f$ so that $f^*g$ satisfies a gauge condition. He appears to be doing this as follows: Instead of finding $f$ directly, he wants to solve for a $1$-parameter family $f_t$, $0 \le t \le T$ (where $T$ could be $\infty$) of diffeomorphisms such that $f_0$ is the identity map and $f_T$ is the diffeomorphism that satisfies the gauge condition. He then does this by solving a PDE roughly of the form
$$ \partial_t(f_t^*g) = \dots, $$
where the right side is defined using the gauge condition.
For each $x \in M$,
$$ c_x(t) = f_t(x) $$
is a curve in $M$ such that $c_x(0)=x$ and $c_x'(0) \in T_xM$. Therefore,you get a vector field $X$ on $M$, where
$$ X(x) = c_x'(0). $$
This vector field can be called an infinitesimal diffeomorphism but it would be better to call it an infinitesimal deformation of the identity map.
If you set $$ h = \left.\partial_t\right|_{t=0}f_t^*g, $$
and $\xi_\mu = g_{\mu\nu}X^\nu$, then indeed
$$ 
h_{\mu\nu} = \nabla_\mu\xi_\nu + \nabla_\nu\xi_\mu.
$$
Here, $h$ can be called an infinitesimal deformation of the metric $g$. $h$ itself is not a metric.
